# Angular ui-grid scope.$apply not working in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) in my application.

I use `cellTemplate` in `columnDefs` to delete the row and for that i use following directive.

CellTemplate:

```
<a href ng-confirm-click confirmed-click="deleteProductFn(row.entity._id)"> <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i> </a>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('ngConfirmClick', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure want to delete?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click', function (event) {
                    if (window.confirm(msg)) {
                        console.log(msg);
                        scope.$apply(clickAction);
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Here `console.log(msg);` print the message in console but next line scope.$apply don't work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I ran a couple of tests and this should work.  I think the problem is in your function argument.  I think you should be passing row.entity not row.entity._id.  Without a working demo I can't confirm, but check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WFjl2xrYhaHW1qls5NgD?p=preview).

Comment: @jme11 what is the problem if i use row.entity._id ???

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  The proper way to pass the row to a function in ui grid is with row.entity.  Did you check the Plunker in my answer.  You can see it working and that's the only change to your code (and I added some css and $event.stopPropagation, so that it would not select the next row after deletion).

Comment: @jme11 yeah i check your plunker. i change in your <a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/XSz1SQVY1rK2bzxsvaZj?p=preview">PLUNKER</a>.

There is no problem if i use row.entity.name.

And i also try to use row.entity though `$scope.$apply()` not work

Comment: I guess I'm not following.  What do you mean by $scope.$apply() isn't working?  Both your plunker and mine seem to be working.

Comment: @jme11 yeah you are right. Both plunker working fine but while i put this in my code none of them working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you're accessing the row.

It should be `row.entity` not `row.entity._id`.

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WFjl2xrYhaHW1qls5NgD?p=preview)

If you want to get to a property in the row, you can do that in your function, but you can't pass the row object to the function by a property.

```
$scope.deleteProductFn = function(entity) {
  //If you want to get to a property on the row entity
  //get it here:
  console.log(entity._id);
};
```

Comment: did you saw the second line in link function `var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;`

Comment: @pankajparkar LOL Nope, missed it.  I guess I need coffee first this morning.  Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is the argument, probably needs $parse. I'll have coffee then fix this answer.

Comment: @pankajparkar  Now that this is fixed, can you remove your downvote?

Comment: Its removed now..Thanks :)